# Is there any reason for returning constant value from hashCode method?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hash, hashcode

I have a question related to extensively discussed topic about hashCode method from java.lang.Object. Simply is there any reason why I should in some use-case return a constant value from `hashCode()`?

```java
public int hashCode()
{
   return 3;
}
```

If you found some article or SO thread which directly answers my question I'd appreciate it. Frankly speaking I couldn't.

**My thoughts**:

From [docs.oracle.com object hashCode()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) (I know quoted many many times here in SO):

> It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables."

So in theory `hashCode()` can return a constant value. In my imagination and what I've read, all objects then will be placed in the same bucket when using for example `HashMap`. As an example lets say 1000 elements will be placed in exactly the same hash bucket (there will be 1000 collisions then in the other words) and to find specific one in the wrong case scenario that 1000 elements would have to be iterated. Then it will perform similarly to `LinkedList` collection (correct me if I am wrong please).

Basing on the above, `hashCode()` can return a constant value like, but it will destroy performance gained from using `hash...` collections. Is there any sense then to do it in some particular example?

**EDIT**:
I found one particular example for having constant `hashCode` method
basing on Vlad's Mihalcea article: [How to implement equals and hashCode using JPA entity identifier](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/), (Hibernate). HashCode differs between entity state transitions, hence it should return constant value. Quote from the article:

> When the entity was first stored in the Set, the identifier was null. After the entity was persisted, the identifier was assigned to a value that was automatically generated, hence the hashCode differs. For this reason, the entity cannot be found in the Set after it got persisted.

So there is a practical example, but as it is pointed out at the cost of performance. If there is a business unique not null identifier apart from entity id, it is better to use it in order to take an advantage of storing entities in the multiple `Hash...` buckets.

Comment: No. Returning a constant hash code is a **terrible** idea. Don't do it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch check out my edit please, that is an example with entities.

Comment: *using the JPA entity business key for equals and hashCode is always best choice.* -- the article then goes on to describe various **bad** choices.

Comment: *to find specific one in the wrong case scenario that 1000 elements would have to be iterated*... Actually, no: Since java 8, when bucket size exceeds 6 it is "treeified" from a  linked list to a balanced binary tree, so time complexity drops from O(n) to O(log n)

Comment: Cool I didn't know that, thanks for sharing your knowledge

Comment: @Bohemian For `HashMap` in Oracle JDK 8, only when the table capacity reaches `64` **AND** the size of the linked list is greater than `8`, the bucket will treeify to a red-black tree.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Not really. If you read [Spring Boot Persistence Best Practices](https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484256251) by Anghel Leonard, he uses a constant value `2021` as the `hashCode` return value for child entity classes. He also points out that if `Set` is used, the size should be small or there will be performance issue. So it's not a terrible idea. Of course, if you have a business key, and the business key of an entity is the same across different Hibernate states, you can use the business key as the `hashCode`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally you would **never return** a static member when overriding hashcode. I've never done this before but the only possible use case I could even imagine would be singletons where you expect runtime to only ever have 1 instance that is not lazily initialized. This is kind of useless because if you design the class to use the singleton pattern you should never need to use equals/hashcode.

Comment: What about ```hashCode``` for entities (check out my edit), apparently there is a practical use case instead of potential singleton pattern for this.

Comment: @jwpol In that article the author doesn't implement the equals/hashcode contract properly because the entity is mutable. That article is not a good example of use-case.

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing it out. So basically ```Hash...``` are not the best collections for entities then, since they are always mutable.

Comment: No worries. In the context of JPA, yes you generally don't override equals/hashcode. The only time I could ever see the reason for overriding equals/hashcode with an @Entity in JPA would be when the primary-key is generated during runtime before insertion and effectively final as well as immutable, such as a UUID that has been randomly generated.

Answer (score 1):

Constant hashCode makes sense when you know the class will have only very few unique instances, ideally only 1.

This situation arises for example when implementing [algebraic data types](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type), or the [Singleton](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) design pattern.

In algebraic data types, all instances of a parameterless data type are equal to each other. Therefore hashCode must return the same value for all instances.

In the Singleton pattern, a class will have only one instance. Therefore it doesn't matter what value hashCode returns, and it can return a constant.